# windows server 2003 "setup cannot copy the file oemsetup.inf"

Tags: windows-server-2003, dell, scsi

I'm trying to install the SCSI drivers for a Dell server with a PERC 4e/si card in it.  I can specify the driver via the F6 and load the driver with S procedure, but once I select the partition and move forward with the installation, I get the message:

```
Setup cannot copy the file oemsetup.inf
```

and no matter what I've tried (new floppy drive, copy files to CD and provide them that way) it either never finds the file or it can't copy it to the disk drive for some reason.

**Any** thoughts will help.

Comment: Where are you getting this error? Immediately after selecting the partition and hitting install? Or does the system go through the install and throws the error after a reboot? The timing of your error will be helpful for diagnosis.

Comment: it is after choosing the partition and is directly after it copies the first file inside setup. I've pressed esc to skip them and I'll let you all know if this works out.

Comment: press "esc" key to skip this file & proceed with the installation. ( It worked for me ) @ Faraz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server 03/xp will only take the driver of a floppy rather than USB stick or CD - are you leaving the floppy in?

If that isn't the issue, you could try slipstreaming the driver onto the windows CD. nLite will do the job, but the results aren't supported by Microsoft. Alternatively you could manually slipstream it (see note), here are two threads with some relevant info:

[Having Windows Keep The Drivers](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/41841-having-windows-keep-the-drivers/)

[Add/slipstream SATA drivers - A fully working solution](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/77999-addslipstream-sata-drivers-a-fully-working-solution/page__st__20)

Note: I believe manually slipstreaming should be supported as this page by MS talks about slipstreaming without mentioning it is an unsupported method.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814847

Comment: Sorry about the st_20"> in front of the 2nd link - tried redoing it a few times and it keeps popping up from nowhere!?!?!

Comment: to answer the first question, it is after choosing the partition and is directly after it copies the first file inside setup.  I've pressed esc to skip them and I'll let you all know if this works out.  The problem with slipstreaming is the disk that is for reinstallation is one that is created by a backup software utility for a bare metal restore.  If the skipping of the files fails, i'll try to slipstream it and see wha happens.

Comment: The st_20" is a markdown glitch because the tail end of your second link contained reserved characters.  I've fixed it up a bit.

Comment: +1, I recall now that Slipstreaming was the only thing that saved me from this problem.